# Use Tcl library with C code gets errors

Tags: tcl, dev-c++

1. softwarre: ActiveState ActiveTcl 8.5.13.296436/Win7/DEV C++ 5.4.1.
2. ActiveTcl is installed at D:/TCL/.
3. error information:

   ```
   E:\src\c\tcl\main.oIn function `Tcl_AppInit':
   8E:\src\c\tcl\main.cundefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_Init'
   E:\src\c\tcl\main.oIn function `main':
   14E:\src\c\tcl\main.cundefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_Main'
   E:\src\c\tcl\collect2.exe[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
   26E:\src\c\tcl\Makefile.winrecipe for target 'tcl_test.exe' failed
   ```
4. c source code:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <tcl.h>
   #include <tk.h>

   int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp)
   {
       return (Tcl_Init(interp) == (TCL_ERROR))?TCL_ERROR:TCL_OK;
   }

   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       printf("--- Tcl Third-Party Shell Start ---\n");
       Tcl_Main(argc, argv, Tcl_AppInit);
       printf("--- Tcl Third-Party Shell End ---\n");

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access those functions (notably, `Tcl_Main`) you *must* link your code against the Tcl DLL (which I think will be `tcl85.dll` in your installation); it's not a symbol that is exported through Tcl's stub linking mechanism. I don't know exactly how you do that on Windows (nor exactly where it will be located) but instructing your build environment to use the DLL should not be too difficult.

FWIW, `Tcl_Init` always returns either `TCL_OK` (i.e., 0) or `TCL_ERROR` (i.e., 1). You can just return the value directly from your AppInit function if you're not going to install your own commands and functionality after basic initialization.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit I could reproduce and solve this in Visual Studio.

You just have to add `D:\Tcl\lib\tcl86.lib` to the "Additional Dependencies" under "Linker/Input".

This solved the problem for me.

#### Edit

You could either pass `Tcl_Init` to `Tcl_Main` (If you don't have to do any specific initialization) or just return the result of `Tcl_Init` like this:

```
int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
    return Tcl_Init(interp);
}
```